# How to find Url for uploaded Icon in Post Category

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I set up an advanced custom field to add a category icon by uploaded an image to a post category. It seems to function but I don't have the right PHP target to pull the image URL.

How do I write this correctly?

I haven't tried any direct solutions besides playing around with PHP that I don't really know.

```
 <div class="cat-icons"><img class="category_icons" src="(<?php 
 the_field('category_icons');?>)"></div>
```

Front end output displays this when I inspect element:

```
 <div class="cat-icons"><img class="category_icons" src="()"></div>
```

Display uploaded image.

Example webpage:
http://xh3.afa.myftpupload.com/hall-of-fame/